# Amazon S3 Multiple Custom Domain Without Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is it possible to setup Amazon's Simple Storage Solution to use custom domains (storage-01.example.com, storage-02.example.com, storage-03.example.com, ...) without using Cloud Front? I don't really care about having an 'edge' network, but do want the browsers to make parallel requests for assets. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unless you duplicate your keys into multiple S3 buckets. This is because S3 uses the Host header value as a reference to the bucket.

I guess you could be sneaky and take advantage of the different URL styles. But it's a horrible suggestion and I would never implement it.

- http://www.mybucketdomain.com/foo.jpg
- http://www.mybucketdomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/foo.jpg
- http://s3.amazonaws.com/www.mybucketdomain.com/foo.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll be forced to pay for cloud front. Thanks for the response!